# changing one compilation of make

Tags: compiling, configuration, make

Is it possible to change some specific compilation made when executing Make, say by appending some new option for the compiller used for one target? One thing I want to do is to modify options because one of the targets is too big for compilation I read that it is possible to add -mbig-obj for GCC, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596876/object-file-has-too-many-sections/19341973#comment28665192_19341973), now I would like to pass it as I use the command Make for that particular target crashing my build.

Comment: Yes. Now we need a bit more information to go on, such as what options the makefile is expecting or what changes you might want to make to it.

Comment: appending is possible if the Makefile has left an undefined variable around for such purpose, like EXTRA_CPP_FLAGS that it passes to the c++ call; in that case just `make EXTRA_CPP_FLAGS=-O mytarget.o` -- otherwise you'll have to modify the Makefile to include the extra variable.

Comment: If you're referring to `-mbig` then AFAIK it's an option related to the endianness of the target processor - I don't think it's anything to do with how "big" the target is. Perhaps it would be better to post a question about the actual problem you are trying to solve.